# Veracrypt with batchfile: how can execution be stopped if drive is not mounted?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, veracrypt

I have a simple batch-file which starts first veracrypt and after mounting another batch-file:

```
C:
cd C:\Program2\VeraCrypt
veracrypt /v \Device\Harddisk2\Partition1 /l L /a /p 123xyz /q 

cd /D D:\backup
start_backup.bat
```

`start_backup.bat` starts a backup using robocopy (Windows 10) which updates/copies files from one drive C to an external encrypted harddrive D respectively L (mount name).

If veracrypt can't mount the drive for any reason (e.g. there is no drive) the batch `start_backup.bat` will be started without backup since encrypted drive is not accessible. How can I avoid the start of `start_backup.bat` in case the drive couldn't be mounted?

The batch-file is written with commands of cmd.exe.

Comment: I would assume something like `If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B 1` in place of your empty line would be worth a try.

Comment: If `veracrypt` should not provide a meaningful errorlevel, [if not exist L:\.](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) may be helpful.

Comment: @Compo I tried it and it works. Veracrypt gaves me the warning: *The system cannot find the path specified* and stops.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is using operator: **`&&`** and **`||`** ...

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "C:\Program2\VeraCrypt"
(
.\veracrypt.exe /v \Device\Harddisk2\Partition1 /l L /a /p 123xyz /q 
) && (
cd /D "D:\backup" & call start_backup.bat
) || (
echo/ something really wrong is going on here....
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
goto :EOF
) 

rem ::  continue with more task here.... or goto :EOF
```

---

- Or...

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "C:\Program2\VeraCrypt"

.\veracrypt.exe /v \Device\Harddisk2\Partition1 /l L /a /p 123xyz /q  && (
cd /D "D:\backup" & call start_backup.bat ) || (
echo/ Something really wrong is going on here....
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & goto :EOF ) 

rem ::  continue with more task here.... or goto :EOF
```

---

- Option to go through three attempts and with a timeout of 30 seconds

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "C:\Program2\VeraCrypt"
:loop
set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
(
.\veracrypt.exe /v \Device\Harddisk2\Partition1 /l L /a /p 123xyz /q 
) && (
cd /D "D:\backup" & call start_backup.bat
) || (
echo/ something really wrong is going on here....
if "!_cnt!"=="3" (
     echo/ Some is really wrong here....
     %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & goto :EOF 
    ) else (
     echo/ Let's try +1 times until 3 [!_cnt!/10]
     %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe 30 
     goto :loop
   )
)
```

---

- Option to go through three attempts and with a timeout of 30 seconds by using **`if !errorlevel! 0/1 else`** as suggested by **[@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)**...

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "C:\Program2\VeraCrypt"

:loop
set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && type nul>nul

.\veracrypt.exe /v \Device\Harddisk2\Partition1 /l L /a /p 123xyz /q 

if !errorlevel! == 0 (
       cd /D "D:\backup" & call start_backup.bat
     ) else (
       echo/ Something really wrong is going on here....
       if "!_cnt!"=="4" (
            echo/ Some is really wrong here....
            %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & goto :EOF 
           ) else (
             echo/ Let's try +1 times until 03 [0!_cnt!/03]
             %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe 30 
             goto :loop
          )
     )
```

---

**[Where does goto eof return to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to/37518000)**

[Operator/Syntax Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

Comment: It works like `If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B 1`. I supposed that when I start the batch-file by clicking on it the terminal remains until I press a key (due to: timeout -1). This was not the case. Nevertheless, I learned from this code.